# delete certain rows from sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, ios, json, sqlite

I am trying to delete creation rows from my database . But it fails to do so I have date specific contents which gets duplicated in my table so I want to delete entries for a specific date and add them every time I establish a connection

My code is :

```
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"person.sqlite3"];
}


    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@", today);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

    if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)
        != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }


    NSString * dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    if(deleteStmt == nil)
    {
        const char *sql = "delete from SHOPPER where DATE = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
    sqlite3_bind_text(deleteStmt, 3, [dateString UTF8String],-1, NULL);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);

    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to sqlite3_bind_text should be 1, instead of 3.
It means the index of '?' character in the prepared statement, and
because there is only one '?' in your delete statement, it must be 1.

```
//When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
sqlite3_bind_text(deleteStmt, 1, [dateString UTF8String], -1, NULL);
```

Then, why you declare deleteStmt as static, and create only once?
I think it should be created for open database, and because you open
and close database every time, you should create (and finalize, not reset)
deleteStmt every time, too.